# Why Binding Syntax Differs when we are writing in nested XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Why Binding Syntax Differs when we are writing in nested XAML . For Example :

```
 <extensibility:CommandBehavior 
       Command="{Binding SelectionChanged}"  
       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=modeItemsListBox,Path=SelectedItems}" >
```

In above example I have  `CommandParameter`  have `ElementName` and `Path` without any quotes.

But the same can be written as:

```
<extensibility:CommandBehavior
      Command="{Binding SelectionChanged}">
      <extensibility:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter>
            <Binding ElementName="modeItemsListBox"="SelectedItems" />
      </extensibility:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter>
</extensibility:CommandBehavior>
```

Where `ElementName` and `Path`both are inside quotes. Is that just an inconsistency or I am missing some hierarchy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two snippets of code you're showing both instantiate the `Binding` class as a `MarkupExtension` and allow it to provide the value for the `CommandParameter` property of your `CommandBehaviour`.

The second variant (the one you call "nested XAML") could be called the canonical way of instantiating the `Binding` class and providing values for properties: The class name is the element name, each property is an attribute and it follows all the conventions of XML: all attribute values must be quoted.

This canonical syntax is, of course, kind of heavy if you need to set lots of properties using markup extensions, so an alternative short-hand syntax was introduced: If you need to set the value of a property named `CommandParameter` using the markup extension `Binding`, you can do that using the simple `CommandParameter="{Binding ...}"` XML syntax. The curly braces in the value are very important, they tell the XAML parser to treat that attribute value differently. You'll need to set property values for the newly instantiated Binding class, and you can't use the usual XAML syntax of `name="value"` because you're writing this *inside* an attribute value, so the quotations are skipped.

Hope this explains it all.